# Remove a substring from a string divide by a space

Tags: java, talend

For example I have a few address strings like "999 SpringRoad Toronto ON L9V167" or "666 York Ave East London Ontario N9T6T4" and I want to delete everything after province so that the new strings would be "999 SpringRoad Toronto" and "666 York Ave East London".
The problem I had is that if I use .split(" ") different address will be divide into different number of parts, the only consistent between these data is that the last 2 things will always be a province followed by a postal code. Is there a way to separate the string based on that?

This is for talend TMap expression filter

Comment: Why don't you split(" ON ")?

Comment: oh wow that was simple, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In pure Java, you could handle this via a regex replacement:

```java
String address = "999 SpringRoad Toronto ON L9V167";
String output = address.replaceAll("\\s+ON.*", "");
System.out.println(output);  // 999 SpringRoad Toronto
```